# Created site from image on azure, fstab read only (linux vm)

Tags: linux, azure, server, readonly

I deployed a site on an azure linux (debian) vm from an image.  Using their image capture process, the original vm is deleted.  There was a raid 0 disk on the the previous deployment which I did not change the fstab file before creating the image.   Now fstab is in read only mode probably because the UUID for the raid is no longer correct.

As it is in read only I cannot make the proper edits to link the new UUID of the RAID disk drive/blob.

I've tried mount / -o remount,rw and similar commands but it says "only root can do that".  I am the only user on the system and sudo -l confirms that I should be able to run all commands.

Also tried changing write permissions but the response again is that only root can do that.

Any other ideas on how to correct the fstab file.   The only thing i can think of is to attempt to download, fix, then replace fstab but i might not have permission for that either.

Thanks

Comment: Or rather help fixing permissions might be a better solution if you have any ideas on how to do that.

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming questions only. From the SO help pages: "Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)."

Comment: I'm having the same issues with writing to other config files.

Comment: My mistake, thanks kaylum